# how to fill missing values with a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([(1, 2), (3, 4), np.nan], (10, 10)))
df
```

[image]

***how do I fill those `NaN` with `(0, 0)`?***

---

I've put this hack together but I'm assuming there is a more direct way.  And this doesn't work for a `pd.Series`

```
df.stack().unstack(fill_value=(0, 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do with `.applymap`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([(1, 2), (3, 4), np.nan], (10, 10)))

df.applymap(lambda x: (0,0) if x is np.nan else x)
```

This will work for a `pd.Series` if you use `apply`:

```
df[0].apply(lambda x: (0, 0) if x is np.nan else x)
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. You could simplify it to: `df.applymap(lambda x: (0,0) if x is np.nan else x)`

Comment: Don't use `x is np.nan` but rather `np.isnan(x)`. `is` means "is the same object", and you may have `x is np.nan` false with `np.isnan(x)` true.

Answer (score 2):

I like your workaround better than this, but it should get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([(1, 2), (3, 4), np.nan], (10, 10)))

idx_arrays = np.where(df.isnull())
idx_tups = zip(idx_arrays[0], idx_arrays[1])

for tup in idx_tups:
     df.loc[tup] = (0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension of `df.fillna()` that can deal with `(list, tuple)` imputation in addition to the original `(dict, number)`:

```py
def fillna_df2_by_df1_mode(df1, df2):
    """fill missing values in df2 with corresponding column mode (could be tuple/list) in df1; it's a extension of df.fillna() in Pandas
    Args:
        df1: e.g. train_df
        df2: e.g. test_df
        flag_stack_d1_d2 (bool, default True): return pd.concat([d1,d2]) or just d2
    Return:
        df: vertically concat df1 and df2 with df2'missing value filled, can be use by fastai tabular
        splits = (df.index[:df1.shape[0]], df.index[df1.shape[0]:])
        d2: d2 after imputation

    """
    # judge if the mode of a column is tuple/list: True/False
    is_tup = [isinstance(x, (list, tuple)) for x in df1.mode().iloc[0]]
    tup_cols = [col for (col, boo) in zip(df1.columns, is_tup) if boo]
    nontup_cols = [col for (col, boo) in zip(df1.columns, is_tup) if not boo]
  
    for col in tup_cols:
        df2[col]=df2[col].apply(lambda x: df1.loc[:,col].mode().iloc[0] if x is np.nan else x)

    splits = (df1.index, df2.index) 
    df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    
    df.loc[splits[1],nontup_cols] = df.loc[splits[1],nontup_cols].fillna(df.loc[splits[0],nontup_cols].mode().iloc[0]) # imputation method: for each column, use train data majority to fill missing value in validation data
    df2 = df.iloc[df1.shape[0]:,:]
    return df, splits, df2
```

For example, if you wanto to do fillna on df2 by df1 col-wise mode (majority):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[(1,2),(1,2),np.nan], 'c2':[list('aaa'),list('bbb'),list('aaa')], 'c3':[1,1,2],}, index=[1,2,3])
        

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[(111,222),(111,222),np.nan,(333,333)], 'c2':[list('xxx'),list('xxx'),list('yyy'),np.nan],'c3':[333,np.nan,np.nan, np.nan]}, index=[11,22,33,44])
        
df, splits, df2 = fillna_df2_by_df1_mode(df1, df2)
df
```

OR if you want to do fillna on df2 by its own col-wise mode (majority)

```py
df, splits, df2 = fillna_df2_by_df1_mode(df2.copy(), df2)
df2
```